# How to Get My Database to work? Firestore

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unable to see any Firestore DB entry from my registered User. I can see only the authentication data on Firebase.

```
private void SalvarDadosUsuario() {
    String nome = etnome.getText().toString();

    FirebaseFirestore bd = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    Map<String,Object> usuarios = new HashMap<>();
    usuarios.put("nome",nome);

    usuarioID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DocumentReference documentReference = bd.collection("Usuarios").document(usuarioID);
    documentReference.set(usuarios).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
            Log.d("bd","Sucesso ao salvar os dados");
        }

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("bd_erro","Erro ao salvar os dados" + e.toString());

        }
    });
}
```

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
  Log.d("bd","Sucesso ao salvar os dados");
}
```

On this line i tried to change between Void aVoid, and void unused, and seems the same!

Comment: Which `Log.d` statement shows up in your console? The success one of failure?  If failure, can you also share the error?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Dharmaraj asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you change the rules in the firestore from false to true.
Check if the implementation is updated in the grade build doc.

Firestore and authentication there different tools in firebase.
If you’re using in Android studio it’s more simple.
You can see here (1.4) - https://www.krasamo.com/cloud-firestore-firebase-basics/

Comment: its updated and sorted mu rules as well